# Changing all my indents to 3 spaces. Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks, astyle

I have to submit an assignment and they want all the indents to be 3 spaces. I don't know how to change the settings of Astyle.dll so that it will change them 3 spaces instead of the default 4. Any ideas?

Also, Astyle seems to like having no indent between switch() and its cases, and I need there to be an indent there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

All of Astyle's settings are exposed in the Code::Blocks editor settings dialog. To access them, open the `Settings` menu, click `Editor`, and scroll through the sidebar to find the `Default code` entry.

> I have to submit an assignment and they want all the indents to be 3 spaces.

Switch to the `Indentation` tab, found under `Source Formatter` in the sidebar, and change `Indentation size (in spaces):` to 3.

> Also, Astyle seems to like to have no indent between switch() and its cases, and i need there to be an indent there.

If I understand what you need correctly, check the box that says `Indent switches (keyword case:)` and check the box that says `Indent case: statement in switches (commands under case:)`.

You can change any other settings you want as well. When you're done, hit `OK`, then reformat your code and make sure the settings are set the way you want them.